# Detection comparison operators with RegEx

Tags: regex

I have a string like this:

```
>=5 AND <8
```

I want to tokenize this into `>=`,`5`,`AND`,`<`,`8`

I have regular expression to do this:

```
([A-Z,a-z,0-9,<|[<=]|>|[>=],=])\w*
```

which is available here:
[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/GcvA4D/2)

It detects the operators but when I have both `>` and `>=`, this expression groups `>` and `=` which I need to keep them together. is there any way to do this?

Comment: Note that the [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[<=]` will match exactly one character, either `<` or  `=`.

Comment: It groups `>` and `=` and you want to keep them together. So it is working.

Comment: Also, character classes can't be nested. Your regex would match "one of `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`, `,<|=[`", or a `<`, or one of `>=`, followed by the literal string `,=]` (and zero or more alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
[A-Za-z]+|[0-9]+|<=|<|>=|>
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GcvA4D/4)
Put the longer ones `<=` and `>=` before `<` and `>`.

Answer (score 0):

I will go with something shorter:

`[^\d\s]+|\d+`

This is equal to `\D+|\d+` with removing spaces off the first side.

Regex101 [demo](https://regex101.com/r/GcvA4D/5)